# Não consigo importar dados de um CSV para o PostGreSQL com dbWriteTable a partir do R

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

Estou tentando importar um CSV para um database PostGreSQL a partir do R. No servidor do PostGreSQL, criei database vazio, chamado "Dados".

```
    library(RPostgreSQL)
    library(sqldf)

    drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")

    con <- dbConnect(drv, 
             dbname="Dados",
             port = 1704, 
             host="localhost",
             user = "postgres",
             password = "dados")
```

A conexão é bem sucedida:

```
    dbListConnections(drv)
    # [[1]]
    # An object of class "PostgreSQLConnection"
    # Slot "Id":
    # [1] 8652    0
```

Aí crio um data.frame qualquer e depois o salvo num arquivo

```
    tabela <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,NA),
                var2 = c(2,3,4,1))

    write.table(tabela,"tabela.csv", sep = "\t")
```

Mas aí, quando executo o comando `dbWriteTable` ocorre um erro:

```
    dbWriteTable(conn = con, name = "tabela1", value = paste0(getwd(),"/tabela.csv"))
    # Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
    #   RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERRO:  não pôde abrir 
    #   arquivo "c:/users/rogerio/desktop/tabela.csv" para leitura: Permission 
    #   denied )
    # [1] FALSE
    # Warning message:
    # In postgresqlImportFile(conn, name, value, ...) :
    #   could not load data into table
```

A "tabela1" é efetivamente criada no DataBase, no PostGreSQL, mas nenhum dado é importado.

O mesmo procedimento funciona perfeitamente numa conexão SQLite...

Alguém tem algum dica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri que um caminho pode ser o seguinte:

```
  library(data.table)
  postgresqlWriteTable(con = con, name = "tabela1", 
                 value = fread("tabela.csv"))
```

Mas ainda não sei se essa é uma alternativa ótima... O `fread` está carregando tudo na memória RAM, como um data.frame/data.table. Depois é que isso é passado para o servidor SQL.

Se o banco for muito grande, isso pode dar biziu...